# How do I deploy .BNA file on IBM cloud blockchain 2.0 resource?

Tags: kubernetes, ibm-cloud, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer, smartcontracts

I am trying to set up a rest API that is connected to an IBM blockchain resource. I have developed a model file, logic file, and acl file.
I have it all packed up in a nice tidy .BNA, and now i would like to deploy it to a channel of my IBM cloud blockchain 2.0 resource, running on a free kubernetes cluster.

Everything on the cloud blockchain resource is set up perfectly, and all orgs, peers, orderers, msps, and CAs are set up correctly. The channel is set up properly, and has nodes and an MSP connected. I have all the admin cred .jsons

The channel only accepts smart contract files, so I tried repackaging the files (logic.js, permissions.acl, and model.cto) by putting them in a contract folder, and using the IBM Blockchain vsCode plugin to package them as a smart contract, but trying to install on the IBM cloud crashes the browser.

I am thinking maybe I have to remote connect into the IBM kubernetes cluster that the blockchain resource is sitting on, and use the hyperledger composer CLI to install the .BNA
Seems very unintuitive, but thats the one thing I can think to try while I wait for this question to get answered.

I expected to just be able to install the .BNA as a smart contract, like a .cds.

Comment: Any specific error when the browser crashes? And just to confirm you make a .bna by using vsCode plugin, correct? The API you want to make is from your localhost or you will be using IBM platform for that?

Comment: nothing specific, i just get "aw snap, something went wrong"
I made the .BNA with the online playground, but i dont mind packing those same files into a .cds smart contarct. i just dont know how.

Comment: and I want to make the API run as a web application integrated with my front end, registering data to my fabric network that i can view in this IBM cloud blockchain resource.

Comment: For the first one, I can't really suggest a solution. At best, try installing and using the `composer CLI` and the latest version to make the bna file. Composer playground isn't maintained as well imo.

Comment: Yes., I faced the same issue. have you found any solution or alternative for this?

Answer (score 3):

In August 2018, IBM announced that we are no longer investing in Hyperledger Composer, and instead focusing 100% on Hyperledger Fabric. As a result, IBM Blockchain Platform v2.0 will not provide any support or tooling around Hyperledger Composer.

The good news is that we've significantly invested in the programming model (APIs and SDKs) used to write smart contracts and applications in Fabric v1.4, and we've also released some great developer tooling in the form of an extension for Visual Studio Code: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=IBMBlockchain.ibm-blockchain-platform

The extension offers an extensive set of capabilities for writing smart contracts - with tooling for creating new projects, packaging them, deploying them, testing them, and debugging them - all from within one of the most popular IDEs around.

To get started - just install Visual Studio Code, and then the IBM Blockchain Platform extension (there are a few prereqs, check the README first). After that, you will be presented with a homepage that links you to tutorials and samples to help you get started.

Answer (score 0):

For the first one, I can't really suggest a solution. At best, try installing and using the `composer CLI` and the latest version to make the bna file. Composer playground isn't maintained as well imo.
For the second part, in the `connection.json` file and docker there will be a bunch of IP addresses that look something like `localhost:7040` and so on for the CA, orderer, org and peer. You will need to replace these using the IPs given by IBM.  The examples on github that demonstrate integration are to do with `nodejs SDK` and not composer, however you can refer to https://github.com/IBM-Blockchain/vehicle-manufacture to get the idea.

[This link](https://hackernoon.com/deploy-a-business-network-on-free-ibm-blockchain-starter-plan-93fafb3dd997) is the only I could find for Hyperledger Composer and IBM platform.
(comments were getting too long to fit)

Comment: I just cant find that connection profile .json anywhere in the blockchain 2.0 service.
i know where to get it from the original IBM cloud blockchain resource, but I cant find out how to connect to the 2.0 beta

Comment: Thing is I have not used it for composer, but have deployed using the `nodejs SDK` so there might be some differences. Does your page look like this - https://github.com/IBM-Blockchain/vehicle-manufacture#5-configure-certificates There is an overview button that should give you connection.json

Comment: Just adding a comment to this answer (for other's benefit / for clarity): Answer #1 above is the definitive answer to this S/O question and status concerning IBM Blockchain Platform 2.0 support for Hyperledger Composer, where the .bna/smart contract archive originates.